# How to fix React Native Navigator is not working

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-navigator

```
class LinkButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.7} style={styles.btn} onPress={this.props.pageNavi}>
                <Image source={this.props.url}  style={styles.btnImg}/>
                <Text 
                    style={{fontSize: width(2.6)}}
                >
                    {this.props.text}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

class Footer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <LinkButton 
                    url={require('../../assets/img/footer/ayuda.png')} 
                    text="Ayuda"
                    pageNavi={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Servicio") }
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

But after pageNavi, i get an error "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')"
Here I want to know what is the problem with this.
Thanks

Comment: where are your navigator codes? is Footer a screen?

Comment: no it is not an individual screen. navigation is in home.js

Comment: then did u pass navigation to Footer? <Footer navigation={this.props.navigation} />

Comment: i ddin't. But it worked without it. If i should do then to where?

Comment: I created an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the navigation props to all the components you want to use navigation.navigate.

For example in your home screen, that renders the Footer component.

```
<Footer navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

This will make this.props.navigation available in Footer component

Comment: I am using <stack.navigator> on home js. how can i change? please help me

Comment: can you help me in details? please!

Comment: I've asked for the navigator codes, but you don't want to edit your question to share the code with us...

Comment: Anyway thanks, someone special. I solved the problem with your tip!!! Really Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
class Footer extends React.Component {

    navigateToScreen = () => {
     this.props.navigation.navigate("Servicio")
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <LinkButton 
                    ......
                    pageNavi={this.navigateToScreen }
                />
            </View>
        );
 }



class LinkButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.7} style={styles.btn} onPress={() => this.props.pageNavi()}>
               .....
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply again! but it is not working. still same error

Comment: It is not working also. From the start. just get same error before loading page. Before, i get an error after  i click the footer tab.